# Ubuntu 18.04 after PPTP session default route

Tags: pptp

I connect to several PPTP networks using network manager. No problems there, but when I disconnect I loose internet access completely.
The 'route' command shows that even after the PPTP disconnects I still have the remote IP as the default route.
If I restart the nic in the network manager I get my my proper local route again.